# How can i make press event with Javascript (jquery, dojo)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, mootools, touch

In the touch screen.

- if i keep press in the center of a screen for 20 seconds, i want to show alert("This is a secret window");
- If i pressed for 5 seconds each corners in the touch screen as: top/left top/right bottom/right bottom/left it will show alert("This is more secret window");

How do i do this in jQuery/Dojo or Mootools or in plain Javascript? Any one ever did this? I do not find any "pressed" event with time set.

Note: there will be also many normal press inputs, so i want to do it in optimized way, for real-time actions except those two.

Comment: Define "press" - do you mean a touch event? Or a mouse click? Or a pressed key?

Comment: @Pekka: In touch screens, you press with your finger (1 or 2 seconds in general you have quick clicks such as mouse), but my case is a long duration click (where you touch the screen and hold it for 20 seconds, only in that case above 20 seconds it should trigger foo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two event handlers and a timer.

```
// Put this lot in a closure so you don't pollute the global namespace.
(function () {
    var timer;
    function onTouchStart() {
        timer = setTimeout(doTheThing, 20*1000);
    }
    function onTouchEnd() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    function doTheThing() {
        alert('foo')
    }
})();
```

Bind onTouchStart/End to the appropriate events on the appropriate elements.

See a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZEgb/) altered to operate with a mouse button and for 5 seconds (because 20 is too much time to hang around for this test).

Comment: It does not work. Please note "you use your finger in the touch screen and keep press it on for 20 seconds, in that case it will show foo". In other cases you have real-time actions.

Comment: @LearnFedora — Err, it should work, that's what the `setTimeout` bit is all about.

Comment: I was testing that for a while with my touch screen. And when i press "once" and leave my fingure. After 20 seconds it shows "foo". But the case was "if you press and hold your fingure for 20 seconds, in that case it will only show foo".

Comment: By "Leave" do you mean "Remove"? Because if you do mean "Leave it touching the screen" then I can't tell the difference between what you say does happen and what actually happens.

Comment: (leave not as remove i mean). See more details here for example: "You go to Bank ATM machine, you are the senior technical person, you know the codes how to use it. So, You touch the center button which is single click (this is general clicks). Our goal: You touch another center button and keep your finger pressed do not REMOVE it for 20 seconds then it shows alert(foo)"

Comment: Yes? That is what my code does. I've updated it with a link to a JS fiddle to prove it.